# redirect users to the login page

Tags: php, authentication

I've got the following login script..

```
<?php
$name = $_POST["name"];
$password = $_POST["password"];
$query = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = '$name'
         AND password = '$password'";
$q=mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());
$result = mysql_query($query);
if (mysql_fetch_row($result)) {
  /* access granted */
  session_start();
  header("Cache-control: private");
  $_SESSION["access"] = "granted";
  header("Location: ./menu.php");
  } else
  /* access denied &#8211; redirect back to login */
  header("Location: ./login.html");
  ?>
  mysql_close();
  ?>
```

But what would I now need to "menu" to redirect users who are not logged in to the login page? to prevent direct access?

Thanks.

Comment: Just FYI, you have two closing "?>" tags.

Comment: Don't forget to escape $name and $password; and you really should be salting and hashing your password

Answer (score 4, accepted):

in menu.php?

```
session_start();
if (!isset($_SESSION['access']) || $_SESSION['access'] != "granted") {
  header("Location: ./login.html");
  exit();
}
```

Comment: Don't forget a session_start() at the top

Answer (score 2):

You have to put something like this at the top of menu.php:

```
<?php
    session_start();
    if(!isset($_SESSION['access']) || $_SESSION['access'] != 'granted'){
        header("Location: ./login.html');
    }
?>
```

And don't forget to sanitize your query input:

```
$name = mysql_real_escape_string(stripslashes($_POST["name"]));    
$password = mysql_real_escape_string(stripslashes($_POST["password"]));
```

And don't forget to call `session_start();` at the beginning of each script that uses `$_SESSION`

Comment: `stripslashes` is only needed if he has magic_quotes_gpc enabled

Answer (score 1):

Check the value of `$_SESSION["access"]` on the top of your menu.php. Also, you miss a call to `session_start`. It may not be needed if you have session.auto_start enabled, but it's good habit to explicitly call it.

Answer (score 0):

Check `$_SESSION["access"]` in menu to see if the user is logged in. By the way, you should read on SQL injection and rewrite that SQL query using escaping.